# In Tikz, how can I specify where an edge connects to a child node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a `Tikz` graph that looks something like this:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,shadows,arrows}

...

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    singleNode/.style={rectangle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=green, drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north},
    subtree2/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, draw=none, fill=blue,
        drop shadow, text centered, anchor=north, minimum height=6em},
    subtree3/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, draw=none, fill=blue,
        drop shadow, text centered, anchor=north, minimum height=9em},
    level distance=1em, growth parent anchor=south
]
    \node (k3) [singleNode] {$k_3$} [sibling distance=20em]
    child{ [sibling distance=14em]
        node (k1) [singleNode] {$k_1$}
        child{
            node (A) [subtree3] {$A$}
        }
        child{ [sibling distance=8em]
            node (k2) [singleNode] {$k_2$}
            child{
                node (B) [subtree3, fill=red] {$B$}
            }
            child{
                node (C) [subtree2] {$C$}
            }
        }
    }
    child{
        node (D) [subtree3] {$D$}
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

`subtree2` and `subtree3` represent subtrees of height 2 and 3, respectively. This graph looks almost as I intend it, but the edge from a parent to a subtree connects at the **side** of the triangle, rather than the **top**.

How can I specify that the edge should connect to the **top** of my triangles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is something like

```
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)}
```

in the options to the `tikzpicture`. See the section on "*Edges From the Parent Node*" in the TiKZ manual to see some more examples of what you can do with this. (As it stands, this will give the edges from the parents to the children a very shallow slope; you can rectify this perhaps by having the children descend further from the parents.)